# Can't register app in SoundCloud developer

Tags: soundcloud

When I try to register app SoundCloud page redirect me to Google Forms, where I fill all inputs. On submit I receive a message: "Looks like you have a question or two that still needs attention.", but there are no blank inputs. Any advice?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming or software development.

Comment: SoundCloud have said they are answering all developer questions on stack with the tag soundcloud so maybe don'e close off this question @meager

Comment: @Grace I understand where you're coming from but Stack Overflow is not a general customer support platform and I don't think this question fits the format.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue also and when I changed the app URL and the redirect URI to something simple, for example 'http://www.appname.com' (as oppose to my localhost address), it seemed to work.

I have to say the new app sign-up on SoundCloud is pretty terrible, used to be so much more straight forward.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, you are right. My mistake was that I was set "App URL" field as http://localhost:3000/ , but SoundCloud API needs real URL. I wanted to test this API on local environment, but unfortunately, I can't do this. Also it's very bad that SoundCloud developer registration form bad informative warnings. There are must be message such as: "URL is not valid" in this case. But still thanks)

Comment: I've registered Soundcloud apps that use "localhost:3000" in the past for testing. They still exist in my account. This new "google docs" signup form is just broken currently.

Comment: @internet-nico , I agree with you, I sent request to register new app (which was success) and doesn't receive any response after two days. I'm waiting...

Comment: @yurii-kuzemko Did any of you get your apps approved?

Comment: @yurii-kuzemko would like to know too. Thanks

Comment: @Rima I have no approved apps...

Comment: Hi guys, did http://www.appname.com work for any of ye? My app keeps getting rejected and I think its due to the App Url they are requesting. It is so frustrating the SoundCloud support is soo bad!

Comment: Mine got declined, not sure why they've cracked down on this recently...

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the API docs it specifically says that the scheme needs to be https, but after 6 hours trying to install the SSL, giving up on it the and one last look at the google docs I realize that it said http or https!